# Number of Circuits in Directed graph

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

There are various questions on how to find the number of cycles/circuits in a directed graph.I have mostly visited them, and i did come out with a code which does it.

I am struck at a point where my code doesn't give a cycle/circuit below of length 3.

Code:

```
public class CyclesInGraph {


        //  Graph modeled as list of edges
        static int[][] graph =
                {
                        {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 3},
                        {3, 1}
                };

        static List<int[]> cycles = new ArrayList<int[]>();

        /**
         * @param args
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            for (int i = 0; i < graph.length; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < graph[i].length; j++)
                {
                    findNewCycles(new int[] {graph[i][j]});
                }

            for (int[] cy : cycles)
            {
                String s = "" + cy[0];

                for (int i = 1; i < cy.length; i++)
                {
                    s += "," + cy[i];
                }

                o(s);
            }

        }

        static void findNewCycles(int[] path)
        {
            int n = path[0];
            int x;
            int[] sub = new int[path.length + 1];

            for (int i = 0; i < graph.length; i++)
                for (int y = 0; y <= 1; y++)
                    if (graph[i][y] == n)
                    //  edge refers to our current node
                    {
                        x = graph[i][(y + 1) % 2];
                        if (!visited(x, path))
                        //  neighbor node not on path yet
                        {
                            sub[0] = x;
                            System.arraycopy(path, 0, sub, 1, path.length);
                            //  explore extended path
                            findNewCycles(sub);
                        }
                        else if ((path.length > 2) && (x == path[path.length - 1]))
                        //  cycle found
                        {
                            int[] p = normalize(path);
                            int[] inv = invert(p);
                            if (isNew(p) && isNew(inv))
                            {
                                cycles.add(p);
                            }
                        }
                    }
        }

        //  check of both arrays have same lengths and contents
        static Boolean equals(int[] a, int[] b)
        {
            Boolean ret = (a[0] == b[0]) && (a.length == b.length);

            for (int i = 1; ret && (i < a.length); i++)
            {
                if (a[i] != b[i])
                {
                    ret = false;
                }
            }

            return ret;
        }

        //  create a path array with reversed order
        static int[] invert(int[] path)
        {
            int[] p = new int[path.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < path.length; i++)
            {
                p[i] = path[path.length - 1 - i];
            }

            return normalize(p);
        }

        //  rotate cycle path such that it begins with the smallest node
        static int[] normalize(int[] path)
        {
            int[] p = new int[path.length];
            int x = smallest(path);
            int n;

            System.arraycopy(path, 0, p, 0, path.length);

            while (p[0] != x)
            {
                n = p[0];
                System.arraycopy(p, 1, p, 0, p.length - 1);
                p[p.length - 1] = n;
            }

            return p;
        }

        //  compare path against known cycles
        //  return true, iff path is not a known cycle
        static Boolean isNew(int[] path)
        {
            Boolean ret = true;

            for(int[] p : cycles)
            {
                if (equals(p, path))
                {
                    ret = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return ret;
        }

        static void o(String s)
        {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        //  return the int of the array which is the smallest
        static int smallest(int[] path)
        {
            int min = path[0];

            for (int p : path)
            {
                if (p < min)
                {
                    min = p;
                }
            }

            return min;
        }

        //  check if vertex n is contained in path
        static Boolean visited(int n, int[] path)
        {
            Boolean ret = false;

            for (int p : path)
            {
                if (p == n)
                {
                    ret = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return ret;
        }

    }
```

> **Output that I am getting:**
>
> 1,3,2

**But i should get 3,4 also as `3-4-3` also make a cycle in graph.**

Comment: At what point, when you run this using a debugger, does it behave differently than expected?

Comment: @ScottHunter , i am getting all cycles except of length below 3. More to add worry, i am getting the cycles in some random order. :(

Comment: In order to find all cycles you need to explore every possible path by depth-first search which your program obviously does not

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @ScottHunter, I havent used debugger yet at this program. i will surely do it.